# General Method that outputs the contents of an int array to screen?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing, int

Full Question: Create a method that will output the contents of an array of ints (of any size) to screen.

My attempt (incorrect):

package practical5;

public class Part1_7 {

```
/**
 * constant referring to array length
 */
public final static int ARRAY_LENGTH= 10;

/**
 * A method that outputs the contents of 
 * an array of integers (of any size) to screen
 */
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    int[] contents= new int [ARRAY_LENGTH];

    for (int counter=0; counter<contents.length; counter++){
        //set array contents
        contents[counter]= 1;

        //print array contents
        System.out.println(contents[counter]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why it is incorrect? This should work, the only issue is that you are assigning `1` to all of the array items.

Comment: @SJuan76 Create a **method** that prints int array of **any size**. Clearly, the method should get passed the array as argumet. Which is not the case with main.

Answer (score 1):

you can also print your array as below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
//..
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(YourArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method which would do that, so move the `for` loop to a method and call it in the `main()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] contents= new int [ARRAY_LENGTH];
    // Some code to populate the array - either user input or your custom input values
    printArray(contents);
}

// General method to print any int array
public static void printArray(int[] array){
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like following

```
public static void printArr(int[] arr){
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

If your JDK version > 1.5 use following

```
public static void printArr(int[] arr){
    for (int i: arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not JDK >1.7, but JDK > 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

this is alternative

```
        for (int content:contents){
            //set array contents
            content = 1;

            //print array contents
            System.out.println(content);
        }
```